# WPF DataTemplate to flatten out XML tree to a list?

Tags: wpf, xml, xaml, datatemplate

Given xml that looks like this:

```
<Root>
    <Fruittree name="Apple" ID="2">
        <Branch name="West" ID="1">
            <Fruit name="Foo">
            <Fruit name="Bar">
        </Branch>
    </Fruittree>
    <!-- more fruitrees etc... -->
</Root>
```

Using xaml with a XmlDataProvider and a DataTemplate, I want to display a list, perhaps in a listbox:

```
Apple - West - Foo
Apple - West - Bar
```

So, an item in the list for each Fruit name in the 3rd level of xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a binding to make current location be Root/Fruittree, and use this template.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="flattenTemplate">
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{} {0} - {1} - {2}">
                <Binding XPath="./Fruit/Branch/@Name" />
                <Binding XPath="./Branch/@Name" />
                <Binding XPath="./@Name" />  
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```